# Spring Boot + Hikari datasource + MSSql - Connection Pooling - Application instance dies after 2 days

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, hikaricp, mssql-jdbc

**Problem:**

Using spring boot application with hikari configured as below

**Hikari Config:**

```
HikariPool-1 - configuration:
allowPoolSuspension.............false
autoCommit......................true
catalog.........................none
connectionInitSql...............none
connectionTestQuery.............none
connectionTimeout...............40000
dataSource......................none
dataSourceClassName.............none
dataSourceJNDI..................none
dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>}
driverClassName................."com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
healthCheckProperties...........{}
healthCheckRegistry.............none
idleTimeout.....................600000
initializationFailTimeout.......1
isolateInternalQueries..........false
jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:sqlserver://<server>:<port>;databaseName=<database>
leakDetectionThreshold..........0
maxLifetime.....................1200000
maximumPoolSize.................100
metricRegistry..................none
metricsTrackerFactory...........none
minimumIdle.....................100
password........................<masked>
poolName........................"HikariPool-1"
readOnly........................false
registerMbeans..................false
scheduledExecutor...............none
schema..........................none
threadFactory...................internal
transactionIsolation............default
username........................"username"
validationTimeout...............5000
```

And everything works well with below successful pool status,

```
HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=100, active=0, idle=100, waiting=0)
```

And every time i access the pool connection it add connection to active and clear back to the same status within seconds.

**After 2 to 3 days suddenly application instance getting crashed without any logs in Spring. As i enabled the TRACE mode log in application the last log which shows related to hikari and connection pool as below**,

1. Right exactly from the starting of the spring log, the connection getting dropped from total pool size as below.

   HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=99, active=0, idle=99, waiting=0)

   --omitted

   HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)
2. No trace of kill signal by the way. below is the spring log

**Spring.log**

```
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG c.m.sqlserver.jdbc.Connection - ENTRY
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Driver - ENTRY Arguments not traced.
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG c.m.sqlserver.jdbc.Connection - RETURN false
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG c.m.s.jdbc.internals.SQLServerDriver - Property:serverName Value:<servername>
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG c.m.s.jdbc.internals.SQLServerDriver - Property:portNumber Value:<port>
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG c.m.sqlserver.jdbc.Connection - ENTRY 15,000
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG c.m.s.jdbc.internals.SQLServerDriver - Property:databaseName Value:<databaseName>
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG c.m.sqlserver.jdbc.Connection - RETURN
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG c.m.sqlserver.jdbc.Connection - ENTRY
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection - ConnectionID:48601 created by (SQLServerDriver:1)
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48501): Closing inputStream...
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection - ConnectionID:48601 Start time: 1564566479298 Time out time: 1564566519298 Timeout Unit Interval: 5000
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48501): Closing outputStream...
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection - ConnectionID:48601 This attempt server name: <servername> port: <port> InstanceName: null useParallel: false
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48501): Closing TCP socket...
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection - ConnectionID:48601 This attempt endtime: 1564566484298
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG c.m.sqlserver.jdbc.Connection - RETURN
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection - ConnectionID:48601 This attempt No: 0
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection - ConnectionID:48601 Connecting with server: <servername> port: <port> Timeout slice: 5000 Timeout Full: 40
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48601): Opening TCP socket...
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection - ConnectionID:48601 ClientConnectionId: c82d4e67-ad38-4a63-9833-d36d5f75cc8f Requesting encryption level:OFF
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection - ConnectionID:48601 ClientConnectionId: c82d4e67-ad38-4a63-9833-d36d5f75cc8f ActivityId 56f3e862-55d1-488c-82f0-1d5b04ce316e-1
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.DATA - /<ip>:<port> SPID:0 ConnectionID:48601 ClientConnectionId: c82d4e67-ad38-4a63-9833-d36d5f75cc8f Prelogin request
   ...C............
--ommited
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.DATA - /<ip>:<port> SPID:0 ConnectionID:48601 ClientConnectionId: c82d4e67-ad38-4a63-9833-d36d5f75cc8f Prelogin response
   ................
   ...............
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection - ConnectionID:48601 ClientConnectionId: c82d4e67-ad38-4a63-9833-d36d5f75cc8f Server returned major version:11
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection - ConnectionID:48601 ClientConnectionId: c82d4e67-ad38-4a63-9833-d36d5f75cc8f Negotiated encryption level:OFF
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG c.m.s.j.i.SQLServerConnection - ConnectionID:48601 ClientConnectionId: c82d4e67-ad38-4a63-9833-d36d5f75cc8f Ignoring prelogin response option:5
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48601) Enabling SSL...
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48601) SSL handshake will trust any certificate
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48601) Getting TLS or better SSL context
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48601) Initializing SSL context
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48601) Creating SSL socket
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48601) (ProxySocket): Getting input stream
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48601) (ProxySocket): Getting output stream
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48601) Starting SSL handshake
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyOutputStream@19ee233d Writing 238 bytes
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48601) (SSLHandshakeOutputStream): Starting new TDS packet...
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Writer - TDSWriter@1729dfa8 (ConnectionID:48601) Writing 8 bytes
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48601) (SSLHandshakeOutputStream): Writing 238 bytes...
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Writer - TDSWriter@1729dfa8 (ConnectionID:48601) Writing 238 bytes
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyOutputStream@19ee233d Flushing
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48601) (SSLHandshakeOutputStream): Ignored a request to flush the stream
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream@1dd1b4d8 Reading 5 bytes
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48601) (SSLHandshakeInputStream): Reading 5 bytes...
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48601) (SSLHandshakeInputStream): No handshake response bytes available. Flushing SSL handshake output stream.
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48601) (SSLHandshakeOutputStream): Finishing TDS message
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Writer - TDSWriter@1729dfa8 (ConnectionID:48601) Finishing TDS message
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.DATA - /<ip>:<port> SPID:0 TDSWriter@1729dfa8 (ConnectionID:48601) sending packet (246 bytes)
   ................

   m.....
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48601) (SSLHandshakeInputStream): Reading first packet of SSL handshake response
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.DATA - /<ip>:<port> SPID:0 TDSReader@140283 (ConnectionID:48601 ClientConnectionId: c82d4e67-ad38-4a63-9833-d36d5f75cc8f) received Packet:1 (2885 bytes)
   ...M........@...

   ...m..\2.....
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Reader - TDSReader@140283 (ConnectionID:48601 ClientConnectionId: c82d4e67-ad38-4a63-9833-d36d5f75cc8f) Moving to next packet -- unlinking consumed packet
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Reader - TDSReader@140283 (ConnectionID:48601 ClientConnectionId: c82d4e67-ad38-4a63-9833-d36d5f75cc8f) Reading 5 bytes from offset 0
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream@1dd1b4d8 Read 5 bytes
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream@1dd1b4d8 Reading 2880 bytes
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48601) (SSLHandshakeInputStream): Reading 2880 bytes...
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Reader - TDSReader@140283 (ConnectionID:48601 ClientConnectionId: c82d4e67-ad38-4a63-9833-d36d5f75cc8f) Reading 2880 bytes from offset 5
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream@1dd1b4d8 Read 2880 bytes
 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48601) (PermissiveX509TrustManager): Trusting server certificate
 [https-jsse-nio-8012-ClientPoller-0] DEBUG o.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint - timeout completed: keys processed=6; now=1564566479853; nextExpiration=1564566479853; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
 [https-jsse-nio-8012-ClientPoller-1] DEBUG o.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint - timeout completed: keys processed=6; now=1564566506164; nextExpiration=1564566506164; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]] DEBUG o.a.catalina.session.ManagerBase - Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1564566506252 sessioncount 0
 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]] DEBUG o.a.catalina.session.ManagerBase - End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 0 expired sessions: 0
 [https-jsse-nio-8012-ClientPoller-0] DEBUG o.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint - timeout completed: keys processed=6; now=1564566506853; nextExpiration=1564566506853; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
 [https-jsse-nio-8012-ClientPoller-1] DEBUG o.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint - timeout completed: keys processed=6; now=1564566566220; nextExpiration=1564566566220; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]] DEBUG o.a.catalina.session.ManagerBase - Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1564566566260 sessioncount 0
 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]] DEBUG o.a.catalina.session.ManagerBase - End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 0 expired sessions: 0
 [https-jsse-nio-8012-ClientPoller-1] DEBUG o.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint - timeout completed: keys processed=6; now=1564566506164; nextExpiration=1564566506164; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]] DEBUG o.a.catalina.session.ManagerBase - Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1564566506252 sessioncount 0
 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]] DEBUG o.a.catalina.session.ManagerBase - End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 0 expired sessions: 0
 [https-jsse-nio-8012-ClientPoller-0] DEBUG o.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint - timeout completed: keys processed=6; now=1564566506853; nextExpiration=1564566506853; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG c.m.sqlserver.jdbc.Connection - ENTRY
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG c.m.sqlserver.jdbc.Connection - RETURN false
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG c.m.sqlserver.jdbc.Connection - ENTRY 15,000
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG c.m.sqlserver.jdbc.Connection - RETURN
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG c.m.sqlserver.jdbc.Connection - ENTRY
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48503): Closing inputStream...
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48503): Closing outputStream...
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48503): Closing TCP socket...
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG c.m.sqlserver.jdbc.Connection - RETURN
 [https-jsse-nio-8012-ClientPoller-0] DEBUG o.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint - timeout completed: keys processed=6; now=1564566655887; nextExpiration=1564566655887; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
 [https-jsse-nio-8012-ClientPoller-1] DEBUG o.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint - timeout completed: keys processed=6; now=1564566656240; nextExpiration=1564566656240; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
 [https-jsse-nio-8012-ClientPoller-0] DEBUG o.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint - timeout
 [https-jsse-nio-8012-ClientPoller-1] DEBUG o.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint - timeout completed: keys processed=9; now=1564566734965; nextExpiration=1564566734965; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
 [https-jsse-nio-8012-ClientPoller-0] DEBUG o.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint - timeout completed: keys processed=9; now=1564566735952; nextExpiration=1564566735952; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
 [https-jsse-nio-8012-ClientPoller-1] DEBUG o.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint - timeout completed: keys processed=9; now=1564566735965; nextExpiration=1564566735965; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG c.m.sqlserver.jdbc.Connection - ENTRY
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG c.m.sqlserver.jdbc.Connection - RETURN false
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG c.m.sqlserver.jdbc.Connection - ENTRY 15,000
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG c.m.sqlserver.jdbc.Connection - RETURN
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG c.m.sqlserver.jdbc.Connection - ENTRY
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48507): Closing inputStream...
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] TRACE c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48507): Closing outputStream...
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel - TDSChannel (ConnectionID:48507): Closing TCP socket...
 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG c.m.sqlserver.jdbc.Connection - RETURN
 [https-jsse-nio-8012-ClientPoller-0] DEBUG o.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint - timeout completed: keys processed=9; now=1564566736952; nextExpiration=1564566736952; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
```

What must be wrong in this process? And why this sql connection logs above shows like closing a socket? and why did hikari suddenly dropping the connections and tomcat process also dies. Please help.

Comment: I know this is old, but did you managed to fix it? if so, how?